# To determine total runtime from excel using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the below columns in excel file i need to find the total runtime using python pandas.

| Stage | JobName | BaseLineStartTime | BaseLineEndTime | StartTime-2Mar21 | EndTime-2Mar21 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| App1 | JobName1 | 20:00:00 | 20:11:45 | 20:05:31 | 20:18:43 |
| App2 | JobName2 | 20:00:00 | 20:12:11 | 20:05:31 | 20:23:11 |
| App9 | JobNamex | 20:11:46 | 20:25:41 | 20:23:12 | 20:43:33 |
| Day1 | JobName1 | 20:25:42 | 20:30:42 | 20:43:44 | 20:48:44 |
| Day2 | JobName2 | 20:30:43 | 20:31:43 | 20:48:45 | 20:49:50 |
| Day2 | JobName3 | 20:30:43 | 20:40:43 | 20:48:45 | 20:58:45 |

Note: I will have more columns based on the runtime dates.

To find the total run time using the logic (App9(EndTime) - App1 (StartTime) & (Day2(EndTime of jobname2 or jobname3 which runs later) - Day1(StartTime)

I need to print the result in below format

| Stage | BaseLineRunTime | Runtime-2Mar21 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| App | 00:25:41 | 00:38:02 |
| Day | 00:15:01 | 00:15:01 |

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. If you need to column names and other things for multiple time frames, that's quite a bit more logic, but you can start here.

This makes the assumption you can sort rows correctly and the variable names are somewhat consistent so you can use `groupby()`

See comments inline

```
import io
import datetime
data = '''
Stage   JobName BaseLineStartTime   BaseLineEndTime StartTime-2Mar21    EndTime-2Mar21
App1    JobName1    20:00:00    20:11:45    20:05:31    20:18:43
App2    JobName2    20:00:00    20:12:11    20:05:31    20:23:11
App9    JobNamex    20:11:46    20:25:41    20:23:12    20:43:33
Day1    JobName1    20:25:42    20:30:42    20:43:44    20:48:44
Day2    JobName2    20:30:43    20:31:43    20:48:45    20:49:50
Day2    JobName3    20:30:43    20:40:43    20:48:45    20:58:45
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s+', engine='python')
df.sort_values(['Stage', 'BaseLineStartTime'], inplace=True)
# define variable to group by; in this case creating column with 'App' and 'Day'
df['groupkey'] = df['Stage'].str[0:3]
dft = df.groupby('groupkey') # create the groupings

# create your output dataframe with Stage and empty strings for runtimes
df_final = pd.DataFrame({'Stage': ['App', 'Day'], 'BaseLineRunTime': ['',''],   'Runtime-2Mar21': ['','']})

# use [0] for first in group and [-1] for last in group
for gkey in dft.groups.keys():
    # print(dft.get_group(gkey))
    basestart = dft.get_group(gkey).iloc[0]['BaseLineStartTime']
    baseend = dft.get_group(gkey).iloc[-1]['BaseLineEndTime']
    m2Mar21start = dft.get_group(gkey).iloc[0]['StartTime-2Mar21']
    m2Mar21end = dft.get_group(gkey).iloc[-1]['EndTime-2Mar21']
    # print(m2Mar21end, m2Mar21start)
    basetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(baseend, '%H:%M:%S')-datetime.datetime.strptime(basestart, '%H:%M:%S')
    m2Mar21 = datetime.datetime.strptime(m2Mar21end, '%H:%M:%S')-datetime.datetime.strptime(m2Mar21start, '%H:%M:%S')
    df_final.loc[df_final['Stage'] == gkey, 'BaseLineRunTime'] = basetime
    df_final.loc[df_final['Stage'] == gkey, 'Runtime-2Mar21'] = m2Mar21
df_final #print your output dataframe
```

Output

```
  Stage BaseLineRunTime Runtime-2Mar21
0   App         0:25:41        0:38:02
1   Day         0:15:01        0:15:01
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this using the below option not sure if its the best

`NewElapsedTime = time_csv[time_csv['Stage'].str.contains('App')] MaxEndTime = datetime.strptime(max(NewElapsedTime['EndTime'],'%H:%M:%S') MinStartTime = datetime.strptime(max(NewElapsedTime['StartTime'],'%H:%M:%S') print(MaxEndTime - MinStartTime)`

Next trying to loop the columns and store these results.